# Supercooled water freezes immediately

Tags: thermodynamics

Supercooled water immedaitely freezes to ice when a tiny ice is touched to it.How is it possible?

Comment: It's pretty well known that water will freeze if the temperature is cold enough. I think the question that you should ask is, 
how is it possible for supercooled water to be liquid _before_ the tiny crystal touches it? I'm not sure whether that's a better question for this site, or for the [chemistry site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/). It's really a question about _physical chemistry_ which straddles the line between chemistry and physics.

Comment: P.S., Have you read the wikipedia article on the subject? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling